# ALSA Programming - `snd_ctl_card_info ()` issues

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a simple C program to list available ALSA sound cards on Linux. My problem is with a simple printf () statement I'm using for a little debugging. Here's the section of code

```
gchar *card_name;
const gchar *card_id;
gint card;
gint open;
gint get_info;
gint card_number;
gint err;
snd_ctl_t *handle;
snd_ctl_card_info_t *info;

card = -1;

for (;;)
{   
    gchar device[20];

    /* Scans a list of alsa devices. With 'card' 
    at '-1' it will search for the first device. */ 
    if ((err = snd_card_next (&card)) < 0)
    {               
        g_print ("%s.\n", snd_strerror (err));

        return -1;
    }

    /* If 'card' reaches '-1' after finding devices, there
    are no more devices. */
    if (card < 0)
    {
        g_print ("\nNo more sound cards.\n\n");

        return 1;
    }

    /* Setup 'device' with proper syntax needed by other functions. */
    sprintf (device, "hw:%d", card);

    g_print ("%s\n", device);  /* debug */

    /* Open device to probe for hardware info here */       
    if ((err = snd_ctl_open (&handle, device, 0)) < 0)
    {
        g_print ("%s.\n", snd_strerror (err));

        return -1;
    }

    /* Get hardware info after opening device */
    if ((err = snd_ctl_card_info (handle, info)) < 0)
    {
        g_print ("%s.\n", snd_strerror (err));

        return -1;
    }

    /* Card hardware info extracted from 'info'. */
    //card_name = snd_ctl_card_info_get_name (info);
    card_id = snd_ctl_card_info_get_id (info);
    card_number = snd_ctl_card_info_get_card (info);

    g_print ("Card Number:%d Card Name:[%s]\n", card_number, card_id);

    snd_ctl_close (handle);
    snd_ctl_card_info_clear (info);
}
```

The `g_print ()` statement for debugging when not commented out compiles and runs fine. When I comment out the `g_print ()` statement for debugging it compiles but seg faults when I run it. Am I missing something?

Comment: _"When I comment out the g_print ()"_ Which one?

Comment: The one that has `/* debug */` next to it.